# Send form data using jquery 'ajax' and html form 'action'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to implement my form for the following two actions after it is submitted:

1. the form action is called and the data is sent to a database
2. also send this form data to another php file using jquery ajax

It's like performing two actions using a single button, single form

Here's my code:

**tryform.php:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parentForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$('.formSubmitButton').hasClass('submitted'))
    {
      // disable the form to prevent multple clicks
      $('.formSubmitButton').addClass('submitted');
          var $form = $(this);
          var serializedData = $form.serialize();
          request = $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
          url: "postdata.php",
          data: serializedData
      });

      request.done(function(data){
          $('.parentForm').submit();

          // enable the form
          $('.formSubmitButton').removeClass('submitted');
          console.log("Working");
      });
      request.fail(function(){
          console.error("Error occured");
      });
    }
    return false;
});
  });


<!--My Form-->
<form id="parentForm" action="thanks.php">
  First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"/>
  <br/>Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"/>
  <br/><input type="submit" id="formSubmitButton" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

**postdata.php:**

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$lastname1 = $lastname . " from postdata";

//$test_query = "INSERT INTO testuser (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "')";
$test_query1 = "INSERT INTO testuser (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname1 . "')"; 
$result_test1 = mysql_query($test_query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

**thanks.php:**

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$test_query = "INSERT INTO testuser (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "')";
echo $test_query;
$result_test = mysql_query($test_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I've used same insert sql statements for now. The form data is being inserted from postdata.php *(using jQuery ajax)* but NOT **thanks.php** *(using form action)*. Ideally, I would like to have both of them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second call to `$('.parentForm').submit()` does nothing because you prevented the default action and returned false. (and because the form has an id, not a class!)

To avoid this, use the form's submit method rather than triggering the submit event again.

```
$('#parentForm')[0].submit();
```

this will cause the form to submit without triggering any submit event handlers.

(you can now get rid of your submitted class and if statement)

---

Alternatively, simply move your `e.preventDefault` inside the if statement and remove the `return false`.

Comment: 1. I tried using `$('.parentForm')[0].submit();` but I get _"cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"_ although the data is being posted from only "postdata.php".  2. I moved `e.preventDefault` inside the if statement and deleted `return false` but it would still do the same. (only postdata.php works)

Comment: 1. that means your selector is wrong for your form, and would explain why your original code doesn't work. `.` should be `#`.  Updated Answer `:)`